# html image-map for fb-Like

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi i would like to replace a facebook original "like"
with an imagemap squared area, say 50, 50, 200, 200, and hitting that map with a mouse click will trigger the Facebook "like".

I have tried usingjQuery to apply style as a test and it did not apply any change:

```
$('.pluginButtonIcon').css('background-color', 'red');
```

I think it should be simple to run that through jQuery or plain JavaScript.

The key idea now I think is to somehow trigger the code of the Facebook like to act on a click of a mouse anywhere I choose.

Comment: I'll be honest, this sounds dodgy.. haha

Comment: @Lavabeams
i just want the thumb on my landig page ,it looks better than a square look "like" plain text , my image(a backGround image of a landing page) contains that "thumb-up" icon , it just looks cooler ...(:

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole heap of different ways of doing the like button - and you can choose the thumbs-up image if you like.
Use facebook's own page to create a button just like what you want here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

There's also more ideas on controlling like-button images in this question:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/how-can-i-control-the-facebook-like-image
(note that some of the answers seem out of date).